# How to download Blazor server page html result

Tags: blazor-server-side

Under Asp.Net MVC I used to build the body of my mailing messages on a MVC view which the system downloaded through System.Net.HttpWebRequest.
Now that I am migrating to Blazor server, I can browse the page but if I try to download it to fill the body of the message I always get next body:

> Loading...   An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev
> tools for details. Reload X

I tried both through a Blazor page and through a Cshtml razor page. My browser can see both successfully but I always get the same exception.
This is the code I use to download the page:

```
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var contentType = response.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType;
                if (contentType == "application/json" | contentType == "text/html")
                {
                    string responseText = await response.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync() ?? "";
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                        retval.Value = (T)(object)responseText;
                    else
                        retval.Value = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText);

                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    retval.Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sign me up for any responses here.  I, too, would like to use Blazor (Server) to produce a "standalone" HTML page like "Save As Webpage" in Word.  Ping me if you're interested in this scenario or have a solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the problem was on Program.cs from my .Net7 Server side Blazor app.

I was registering HttpClient as follows:

```
var http = new HttpClient();  
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => http);
```

This was Ok to access API data, but for some reason if you try to download a Html page source it throws a System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

The right way to register the service to avoid this exception is:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

The problem is I no longer have a http variable in Program.cs, which I used to preload data from Api before the index page was ready.

Answer (score -1):

Need a bit more detail:

- What line threw the exception?
- What was the exception?
- What was value of `string responseText` or `byte[] result`?

I suspect either the `DeserializeObject` or `Convert.ChangeType` call failed. You should debug this; the answer will probably become apparent as you step through the code.

Comment: No line throws any exception; the exception text comes in the httpresponse

Comment: I assume that you own the code on the server side as well, right? If so, you should be able to debug that to see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: I see that it was indeed something on the server side that you could find by debugging. Glad you found the issue, @MatiasMasso